# How to use the Dell PowerEdge as a normal server?

Tags: home-server

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2950. How do I set it up to be a normal computer?
When I try to install ubuntu it does not see any of the harddrives.
I read somewhere that I have to set up RAID before I can install an OS.
Is this a must?
Is it possible to set this machine up as a normal desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Enter into BIOS, reset all settings to default and reboot. The RAID setup prompt should pop up for you upon first boot.

Comment: If it's anything like the 2500 you can press Ctrl-A at the boot BIOS screen when indicated to configure arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It can be setup as a normal desktop, but why would you want to?  It is going to be like having a hairdryer running next to your desk.  You could easily build a computer for cheap that will outperform the 2950's.